# mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null) while mounting ext4 fs

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, ext4, embedded-linux

I am using Beaglebone black with NFS,
I have formatted internal eMMC with ext4 filesystem,

when i mount the file system using following command message popups telling filesystem is mounted without `journal`, so how can i mount the filesystem with journal,

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p2 /media/emmcrfs/
[10639.836647] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

Another thing i read is ram journal is better for embedded system, is it so ?
How can I set ram journal option ?

Do i have to use `tune2fs` utility ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well with some experiment i found the answer,

I had used `mke2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2` command to format the partition. And after that if i mount `/dev/mmcblk0p2` on the `/media/emmcrfs` mount spits message that it is mounting file system without journal.

when i used `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p2` command to format the partition and then mount `/dev/mmcblk0p2` i see mount giving message that it is mounting file system with journal. For exact message see below command

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p2 /media/emmcrfs/
[ 3172.107869] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

So when i googled it i found that `mke2fs` utility refers `/etc/mke2fs.conf` file for different options. if mke2fs is not given any argument it takes parameters from `[defaults]` from the `/etc/mke2fs.conf` and these `[defaults]` parameters doesn't have journal option.

When i use command `mkfs.ext4` it internally calls `mke2fs` with `ext4` as parameter and because of which `mke2fs` refers parameters for `[ext4]` in the `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. In my case `[ext4]` contains the journaling option so it creates journal.

Hope it helps someone having same question as me :)